# Pex with a time limit

Tags: pex

Is it possible to set a time limit in Pex by command line? If yes, how?

I've been searching about it and I found a [paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/fulltext.pdf) that says:
"Pex uses several heuristics that take into account the structure of the program
and the already covered statements when deciding on the next program inputs.
While the ultimate goal of Pex is to discover all reachable statements, which is an undecidable problem, in practice Pex attempts to achieve high statement
coverage fast. This simplifies the configuration of Pex greatly: the user just has to set a time limit or another rough exploration bound"

It looks like has a way to set a time limit, but it doesn't says how to.

Thanks in advance!